# django-registratio-redux - password_reset_email.html

Tags: django, django-forms

I have searched everywhere and can not find an answer.

I am using django-registration-redux 1.5 with django, I have my templates in the templates folder, but specifically the file "password_reset_email.html" does not load html when I send it, the file to activate the account does load the html correctly.

Thank you

Comment: And you have it under `templates/registration/password_reset_email.html`?

Comment: Yes, i have the template inside that path, django-registration-redux sends the email but don't load html.